# CSS3 360º continuous rotation works in Chrome but spins back in IE

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I am playing with CSS and animations for my website, and really liked the look of the loading CSS that the Drawception website uses. Their code only does a 90 degree animation then resets. I wanted mine to do a full 360 degree rotation as mine would have an image rotating inside it too.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
<style>
.loading-box2{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.loading-box2:before{
    content: '';
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    right: 42%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: shadow360 2s linear infinite;
}
.loading-box2:after{
    content: ':o)';
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: #fffdc9;
    animation: boxbounce360 2s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 42%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  /* colours here added while testing */
    border-right: 1px solid #f00;
    border-top: 1px solid #0f0;
    border-left: 1px solid #ff0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f;
}
@keyframes boxbounce360{
    3.25%,24.25%,28.25%,49.25%,55.25%,74.25%,78.25%,99.25%{border-radius: 3px; border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;}
    0%{transform:translateY(0) rotate(0deg)}
    7.84375%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(22.5deg)}
    13.5625%{transform: translateY(18px) scale(1, .9) rotate(45deg);border-bottom-right-radius: 40px}
    19.25125%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(67.5deg)}
    25%{transform: translateY(0) rotate(90deg)}
    32.84375%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(112.5deg)}
    38.5625%{transform: translateY(18px) scale(1, .9) rotate(135deg);border-top-right-radius: 40px}
    44.28125%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(157.5deg)}
    50%{transform: translateY(0) rotate(180deg)}
    59.84375%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(202.5deg)}
    64.5625%{transform: translateY(18px) scale(1, .9) rotate(225deg);border-top-left-radius: 40px}
    69.28125%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(247.5deg)}
    75%{transform: translateY(0) rotate(270deg)}
    82.84375%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(292.5deg)}
    88.5625%{transform: translateY(18px) scale(1, .9) rotate(315deg);border-bottom-left-radius: 40px}
    94.28125%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(337.5deg)}
    100%{transform: translateY(0) rotate(360deg)}
 }
 @keyframes shadow360{
     0%,25%,50%,75%,100%{transform: scale(1, 1)}
     13.5625%,38.5625%,64.5625%,88.5625%{transform: scale(1.2, 1)}
 }
</style>
<body>
<div class="loading-box2">
</body>
```

And a jsfiddle thing [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DoogleSmile/dj3k7oxo/).

In Chrome, the animation runs perfectly, always rotating the same direction. But in Internet Explorer 11, it gets to 180 degrees then spins back to 0!
Any ideas how I can fix it for IE, preferably without needing any Javascript, but I won't mind if it does need it.

Comment: Having a play with the code, I noticed if I remove all the translateY() and scale() parts out of the keyframes, the animation rotates properly in IE, but obviously it now no longer bounces up and down nicely.
Any ideas what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to hack a fix... I added an extra keyframe:

```
50%{transform: translateY(0) rotate(180deg)}
50.1%{transform: rotate(180.5deg)} <---- this one
59.84375%{transform: translateY(9px) rotate(202.5deg)}
```

Now it no longer looks like it is spinning back half-way through the animation on IE, even though it still is doing!